# Merge Function in pandas library

Tags: python, merge, missing-data

I'm trying to merge two data frames based on a single column. This column contains values starting with '+'. Merge function works fine for all other rows except for rows that have a plus sign. 
Example:

```
      df1                             df2                    df3(expected Output)
Key   Cost  Conversion         Key   avg cost  Revenue        Key   Cost  Revenue  
AAA   12.23     2              +BBB  22.33     1000           AAA   12.23   1000
+BBB  26.24     1              AAA   92.63     5689           +BBB  26.24   5689    
CCC   15.48     0              DDD   35.68     4567           CCC   15.48   4567 

df3(obtained Output)
Key   Cost  Revenue  
AAA   12.23   1000
+BBB  26.24       
CCC   15.48   4567
```

`res = df1.merge(df2[['Key', 'Revenue']], on='Key',left_index=True, how = 'left'`

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce your result

`df1.merge(df2, on='Key')`

```
    Key   Cost  Conversion  avg_cost  Revenue
0   AAA  12.23           2     92.63     5689
1  +BBB  26.24           1     22.33     1000
```

`df2 = pd.read_clipboard()`

```
    Key  avg_cost  Revenue
0  +BBB     22.33     1000
1   AAA     92.63     5689
2   CCC     35.68     4567
```

`df1.merge(df2, on='Key')`

```
    Key   Cost  Conversion  avg_cost  Revenue
0   AAA  12.23           2     92.63     5689
1  +BBB  26.24           1     22.33     1000
2   CCC  15.48           0     35.68     4567
```